# Android - get last saved file name

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a `EditText` where the user can choose the name of the video being saved. I would like to get the name of that file / last file saved.

The directory of the saved files is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyNewApp/MyVidEdits/vidname.mp4"`.

I have tried:

```
String path= "/MyNewApp/MyVidEdits/1414240995236.mp4";
String filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

and it just gives me back the same name `1414240995236.mp4`.

EDIT-------

I forgot to mention that the editText is in a custom alertDialog.

Edit 2 -- More detail---- Not all the processes are included, just the relevant.

```
//This is where I initialise the EditText
public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonExport:
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.myDialog));                      
            View mView = LayoutInflater.from(Activity.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_dialog, null);
            final EditText mText = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
            mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if(!mEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    directoryToStore = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyNewApp/MyVidEdits");

        }

// AND HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL THE EDITTEXT

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    String path= "/MyNewApp/MyVidEdits/1.mp4";//it contain your path of image..im using a temp string..
    String filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    File k = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filename);
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(k)));
```

The problem is that the EditText is set in:

```
View mView = LayoutInflater.from(Activity.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_dialog, null);
final EditText mText = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
```

so I can't just say:

```
String text = mText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Does the user just have to type the file name or does he have to enter the full path with extension ?

Comment: only the name of the file

Comment: Do you want to be able to get the last saved file name later on when the user reopens the app for example ?

Comment: No I don't have to store it, I just want to temporarily use it. It is to send a broadcast so I just want to call it once

Comment: I dont see where the issue is, please provide some code. You already have access to the filename when you get it from the EditText

Comment: @Amroelaswar please see edit 2

Comment: Why not create a class member call it `String lastSaved;` then once you get the filename from the EditText inside your alert djalog you do `lastSaved= mText.getText().toString();` you can then access lastSaved from anywhere

Comment: because I wont be able to use the editText in my custom view, I have to initialise it as `EditText mEmail = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);`

Comment: Yes you still can, add a variable called `String lastSaved;` at class level then it wont have to be final, you can then do `lastSaved = mText.getText().toString();` in your onClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you should do :

```
class myActivity extends Activity {
    String lastSaved = ""; 

    ...

    //This is where I initialise the EditText
    public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonExport:
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.myDialog));                      
                View mView = LayoutInflater.from(Activity.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_dialog, null);
                final EditText mText = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
                mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        if(!mEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                        directoryToStore = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyNewApp/MyVidEdits");
                        lastSaved = mText.getText().toString();

            }

    // AND HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL THE EDITTEXT

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lastSaved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        File k = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filename);
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(k)));
    }
}
```